# Wrong piped type got from HttpClient Post request

Tags: angular, typescript, post, types, angular-httpclient

My service is firing post request like this

```
createDocument(owner: string): Observable<HttpResponse<Document>> {
    return this.http.post<HttpResponse<Document>>(`${this.API}`, {owner}).pipe(
      tap(document => {
        this.dataStore.unshift(document.body!.authenticationMethod, document.body!.assertionMethod)
        this.list$.next(this.dataStore)
      })
    )
  }
```

However the response in the `tap` function doesn't have a `HttpResponse` type instead it is a `Document`.

I was expecting `document` to be a `HttpResponse<Document>` object. My APIs is responding with a `Document` json-like string that is correctly parsed into a `Document` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular HttpClient methods support an option called `observe`.

By default it's `body`. In your case you should specify type `'response'`:

```
return this.http.post<Document>(`${this.API}`, {owner}, { observe: 'response' })
```

Note: I also change type to just `Document` so that TypeScript will automatically recognize `document` parameter as `HttpResponse<Document>`